# Transforming Wide for Long Database, Grouping Variables in R

Tags: r, database, database-design, reshape, wide-column-store

I would like to make a modification to my database. What I am trying to do is transform every row of my database being for a single individual.

I want it to look like this. Example:

```
ID    massaseca Fator   Anexo     Teor  Tempo
1       334,68     AM       c      0       0
1       344,19     AM       c      0      10
1       347,32     AM       c      0      20 
1       350,2      AM       c      0      30 
1       352,52     AM       c      0      40
.        .          .       .      .       .
.        .          .       .      .       .
```

Although I found some examples in the forum, I couldn't solve my problem. I will present both attempts. When I execute the code below, I find that it overrides some variables and is not the way you want.

```
####################################
require(reshape2)
long <- melt(dados1, id.vars = c("Teor", "Fator"))
melt(dados1, id.vars = 1:2)
melt(dados1, measure.vars = 4:45)
melt(dados1, measure.vars = as.character(10,20,30,
                                         40,50,60,70,80,
                                         90,105,120,135,150,
                                         170,190,210,230,250,
                                         270,290,310,330,350,
                                         360,405,450,510,570,
                                         630,690,750,810,870,
                                         930,990,1050,1110,1170,
                                         1230,1290,1350))

################# CASE 2 ###########
####################################
library(data.table)
long1 <- melt(setDT(dados1), id.vars = c("Teor", "Fator"), variable.name = "Tempo")
long1
melt(setDT(dados1), id.vars = 1:2, variable.name = "Tempo")
melt(setDT(dados1), measure.vars = 4:45, variable.name = "Tempo")
melt(setDT(dados1), measure.vars = as.character(10,20,30,
                                                  40,50,60,70,80,
                                                  90,105,120,135,150,
                                                  170,190,210,230,250,
                                                  270,290,310,330,350,
                                                  360,405,450,510,570,
                                                  630,690,750,810,870,
                                                  930,990,1050,1110,1170,
                                                  1230,1290,1350), variable.name = "Tempo")
```

However, with the example above it is filling one variable below another, how to do it?

Comment: It's preferable for you to post a [workable sample of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) here, rather than pointing folks to download a file from a third party site

Comment: Click the link I posted. There are examples of how to add your data to the question or use a commonly-available dataset.

Comment: Looks like a reshaping problem. `tidyr::gather(dados1, Tempo, massaseca, -(1:3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an unambiguous `"id"` column missing, which you may substitute by `cbind`ing the row numbers. Then you could use base `reshape` where we grap the values for the `times` argument from the column names. (Note that you need to add `1` to the `varying`s if you set `id` as first column as I did.)

```
res <- reshape(cbind(id=1:nrow(dados1), dados1), 
               varying=5:46, 
               v.names="massaseca",
               timevar="Tempo", 
               times=as.numeric(gsub("X", "", tail(names(dados1), -3))), 
               direction="long", sep="")
```

#### Result

```
head(res[order(res$id), ])
#      id Teor Fator Anexo Tempo massaseca
# 1.0   1    0    Am     c     0    334,68
# 1.10  1    0    Am     c    10    344,19
# 1.20  1    0    Am     c    20    347,32
# 1.30  1    0    Am     c    30     350,2
# 1.40  1    0    Am     c    40    352,52
# 1.50  1    0    Am     c    50    354,81
```